# Is it possible to add action only at LOOP's final round?

Tags: php

I want to do redirect to other page after finish the loop

something like this

```
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
{
    echo $i;
    header('Location: home.php'); // do this if finish the loop
}
```

Note : My case the redirect has to be in loop because my real code is about upload multiple files in loop  and check file type in loop  so I want to not redirect if it has wrong filetype, and if upload correctly, redirect to home.php page too.  but the problem is when I upload correctly in first round loop it will redirect to home page without doing upload residual files.
and If I put redirect outside of loop ,  the errormessage of filetype will not show because it will redirect to home only.

```
     $path_upload = 'images/cover/';
                $count = count($_FILES["images"]["name"]);
                $allowed_types = array("image/gif", "image/jpeg", "image/png");
                $nl = PHP_EOL.'<br>'; // Linux: \n<br> Window: \r\n<br>
                $arr_newname = array();

                for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++)
                {   
                    $file_type = $_FILES["images"]['type'][$i];
                    $file_name = $_FILES["images"]['name'][$i];
                    $file_size = $_FILES["images"]['size'][$i];
                    $file_error = $_FILES["images"]['error'][$i];
                    $file_tmp = $_FILES["images"]['tmp_name'][$i];

                if($_FILES["images"]["name"][$i] != "")
                {

                    if (in_array($file_type, $allowed_types) && $file_size < 2000000) 
                    {

                        if ($file_error > 0) {

                            echo 'Upload file:'.$file_name.' error: '.$file_error.$nl;

                        } else {

                            $ext = explode('.', $file_name); // explode dots on filename
                            $ext = end($ext); // get last item of array

                            $newname = "album_id".$album_id."_".date('Y-m-d')."_".($i+1).".".$ext;
                            $arr_newname[$i] = $newname;               
                            $path_new_upload = $path_upload.$newname;


                    if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $path_new_upload))
                    {
                        $data = array(
                            'front_pic'.($i+1) => $arr_newname[$i]
                        );
                        $this->db->where('album_id', $album_id);
                        $this->db->update('oav_album', $data);

                         redirect('home.php'); ////////THIS will stop the residual round of loop
                    }

                }

            } 

            else 
            {

                echo 'Invalid file type to: '.$file_name.$nl;
                // continue the code
            }
          }
        }
redirect('home.php'); ////////IF I put this outside loop it will not show error` message but redirect to home
```

Comment: `if ($i == 4) header()`

Comment: You should keep track of the errors in the loop and redirect after the loop depending on the content of the errors variable / array  / etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the statement after the loop so it works at the end of the loop for one time. If you want to use last known `$i` value you can define `$i` before the loop and use it after the loop.

```
$i = 0
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
    //loop
}
$i--;//get last value
echo $i;
header('Location: home.php'); // do this if finish the loop
```